# A common type for all SwiftUI Shapes

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, protocols, shapes

I write a code for SwiftUI that delivers a certain `Shape` depending on an `Enum` parameter. Unfortunately, a `switch` command, which seems natural for the purpose, complains that `Rectangle()`, `Circle()`, and `Diamond()` (my own `Shape`) have all mismatching types.
[image: compiler complaints]

How can I convince Xcode that all these are `Shape`s and all perfectly comply with SwiftUI modifiers in further code?

The code snippet demonstrating the problem:

```Swift
import SwiftUI

enum MaskShapes {
    case rectangle, diamond, circle
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let shape = MaskShapes.diamond
        let mask = switch shape {
        case .rectangle: Rectangle() // Error: Branches have mismatching types 'Rectangle' and 'Circle'
        case .diamond: Diamond() // Error: Branches have mismatching types 'ContentView.Diamond' and 'Circle'
        case .circle: Circle()
        }
        
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
        .background(mask.foregroundColor(.red))
        Spacer()
    }
    
    struct Diamond: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            var p = Path()
            p.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: 0))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.midY))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
            p.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
            p.closeSubpath()
            return p
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Expected effect - achieved with each Shape separately:
[image: Rectangle()]
[image: Diamond()]
[image: Circle()]

Comment: Did you try to extract the `switch` into a method returning `some View`?

Comment: If you truly want a `Shape` in the end you should create a `ShapeBuilder` similar to `ViewBuilder` but if `some View` is ok just use an `@ViewBuilder`

Comment: Maybe not exactly the `ShapeBuilder`, but semantically quite close is `AnyShape` that unifies all different shapes into one type. Thank you @Robin for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making your `shape` typed to `AnyShape` you can make the other shapes also conform to it by wrapping them in `AnyShape(*shape*)` for example: `AnyShape(Rectangle())`

So your switch becomes:

```
let mask = switch shape {
    case .rectangle: AnyShape(Rectangle())
    case .diamond: AnyShape(Diamond())
    case .circle: AnyShape(Circle())
}
```

Making these changes will make it compile + work!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It is even possible to skip `: AnyShape` declaration, as Xcode infers that from the type of switch outcome. Thank you @Robin! :)

Answer (score 3):

What would be nice, would be if SwiftUI supported a `ShapeBuilder` attribute. Maybe you could write it yourself, but I don't expect it will be easy. So here are two possible workarounds:

**1. Create a `ViewBuilder` function to create the specified `Shape`**

*EDIT* I thought `if-else` was needed here, but in fact a `switch` does work (thanks Rob Napier for the tip).

```swift
@ViewBuilder
func mask(shape: MaskShapes) -> some View {
    switch shape {
    case .rectangle: Rectangle()
    case .diamond: Diamond()
    case .circle: Circle()
    }
}

var body: some View {
    let shape = MaskShapes.diamond

    Spacer()
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    .background(mask(shape: shape).foregroundColor(.red))
    Spacer()
}
```

**2. Supply the `Shape` to a generic function**

This approach retains the `Shape` type, so if you wanted to use a modifier that was Shape-specific then you could.

*EDIT* A `switch` works here too.

```swift
@ViewBuilder
func bodyWithShapedBackground<S: Shape>(shape: S) -> some View {
    Spacer()
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .imageScale(.large)
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    .background(shape.foregroundColor(.red))
    Spacer()
}

var body: some View {
    let shape = MaskShapes.diamond
    switch shape {
    case .rectangle: bodyWithShapedBackground(shape: Rectangle())
    case .diamond: bodyWithShapedBackground(shape: Diamond())
    case .circle: bodyWithShapedBackground(shape: Circle())
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first example, `switch` would be fine. ViewBuilder can handle it (and particularly in Swift 5.9).

Comment: @RobNapier You are quite right, I tried it and it works. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Your solution implemented in the code snippet works! Thank you @BenzyNeez for the idea! However, the concept is a bit hacky, as it converts structs conforming to `Shape` protocol to a `some View` which does not conform to the `Shape` protocol anymore. In my real code, I have been using these shapes as parameters for `.clipShape(_ shape:)` modifier.  The modifier does not accept `some View`, unfortunately.

Comment: @Voyteck What about variant 2?

Comment: @BenzyNeez Variant 2 does not deliver the `Shape` protocol conforming result, which is required by the `.clipShape()` modifier in my actual code. Also, the solution with  `AnyShape()` does not make me write additional functions or views, as `AnyShape()` is Swift native.

Comment: @Voyteck With variant 2, you supply the required ```Shape``` to the function ```bodyWithShapedBackground``` and you can use it as a ```Shape``` inside that function. So you can use ```clipShape``` in there, or any other shape modifier. I get it that you prefer the other solution, but I hope you see that the solution here was perfectly valid.

Comment: @BenzyNeez when I put `bodyWithShapedBackground` as a parameter to the `clipShape()`, I get the compiler error: `Instance method 'clipShape(_:style:)' requires that 'some View' conform to 'Shape'`. Variant 2 is valid for the code snippet I created for the question but does not answer the real problem described in the question title, i.e. **A common type for all SwiftUI Shapes**.

Comment: @Voyteck *Inside* the function ```bodyWithShapedBackground``` you can use ```.clipShape(shape)```.