# View generating Shape based on enum

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, enums, shapes

I want to give my view enum as parameter to generate corresponding Shape.

I tried something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NotWorkingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Card(shape: .capsule)
        Card(shape: .circle)
    }
}

struct Card: View {
    let shape: Shapes
    
    var body: some View {
        shape.val
    }
}

enum Shapes {
    case capsule
    case circle
    
    var val: any Shape {
        switch self {
        case .capsule:
            return Capsule()
        case .circle:
            return Circle()
        }
    }
}
```

but Xcode 'Failed to produce diagnostic'

I could do this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct WorkingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Card(shape: Capsule())
        Card(shape: Circle())
    }
}

struct Card<Content: Shape>: View {
    let shape: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        shape
    }
}
```

but I wanted to be able to iterate over all valid shapes.

Is it possible to achieve that without making Card a template? Or maybe I need a wrapper for Card struct?

Comment: See also [A common type for all SwiftUI Shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77272178/20386264)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is the usage of `any Shape`. Use `some View` and use a `Group` or `@ViewBuilder` to return different types.

```
enum Shapes {
    case capsule
    case circle
    
    var val: some View {
        Group{
            switch self {
            case .capsule:
                Capsule()
            case .circle:
                Circle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or:

```
enum Shapes {
    case capsule
    case circle

    @ViewBuilder
    var val: some View {
            switch self {
            case .capsule:
                Capsule()
            case .circle:
                Circle()
            }
    }
}
```

Or even simpler:

If the `Card` View doesn´t contain more than the Shape, conform your enum to View and rename the `val` var to `body`:

```
struct NowWorkingView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Shapes.capsule
        Shapes.circle
    }
}

enum Shapes: View {
    case capsule
    case circle
    
    var body: some View {
        switch self {
        case .capsule:
            Capsule()
        case .circle:
            Circle()
        }
    }
}
```